# Php app refused access to database, but same credentials work from CLI

Tags: mysql, privileges

I am trying to set up a content management system called [CollectiveAccess](https://github.com/collectiveaccess/providence) Providence, but currently I am stuck at getting the php app authenticated on the database.  The initial install page indicates a problem authenticating to the database:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught DatabaseException: Access denied for user 'providenceuser'@'localhost' to database 'providencedb' in /var/www/html/providence/app/lib/Db/mysqli.php:144 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/providence/app/lib/Db.php(134): Db_mysqli->connect() #1 /var/www/html/providence/app/lib/Db.php(108): Db->connect() #2 /var/www/html/providence/app/lib/ConfigurationCheck.php(103): Db->__construct() #3 /var/www/html/providence/install/inc/page1.php(44): ConfigurationCheck::performInstall() #4 /var/www/html/providence/install/index.php(148): require_once('/var/www/html/p...') #5 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/providence/app/lib/Db/mysqli.php on line 144
```

For testing purposes, this question uses [db-connect-test.php](https://gist.github.com/chales/11359952)  which also had issues, but which I was able to get past.
On the first try of the test app, I got access denied.

```
dev-admin@devtest:~$ php -f php_db_test/db-connect-test.php
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in /home/dev-admin/php_db_test/db-connect-test.php on line 10
```

When I ran the same command as superuser, I could connect because it correctly reported:

```
There are no tables<br />
```

With the test app, if I changed the db user 'root' and left the password empty as '', it seems I am able to connect:

However, the same thing did not work for Providence, still giving me an "access denied".

I thought maybe the type of connection was the problem, so I ran:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'providenceuser' AND plugin IN ('unix_socket', 'auth_socket');

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

However that, did not help.
I have also tried changing 'localhost' in the config files to `127.0.0.1` without success.

What else can I try or where else can I look for clues?

Comment: Are you testing this on you local machine or hosted?

Comment: Hosted, accessing via ssh, database and webserver are both on localhost.

Comment: Have you tried creating a database user and using these credentials?

Comment: Yes, I created the database and can log into it from the shell using the same user as specified in the php.

Comment: Without showing username/password etc what is your connection script?

Comment: From the cli `mysql -u username -p`, then enter password. That works.
The script used by the app is here: https://github.com/collectiveaccess/providence/blob/master/app/lib/Db.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was with how I created my database:

```
GRANT ALL ON providencedb TO 'providenceuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passw0rd' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I was able to install when I recreated it like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON providencedb.* TO 'providenceuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passw0rd' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I was able to proceed with the installation. The other things that were different about the new installation are that I used Ubuntu 18.04 and php7.2.